# Como resolver? No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query]

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jpql, boot

Então Galera Estou com um problema ao realizar uma consulta através de uma @query, bem basicamente o que eu preciso é de uma lista de uma coluna status no bd que me retorne apenas os alunos que estão com o status "Concluido" para isto eu escrevi a seguinte query `@Query("select p.status from Aluno p where p.status = 'Concluido' ")`
a principio não tive nenhum problema, porém quando fui para view o hibernate lançou esta exceção.

> Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List] for value '[Concluido]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.academy.model.Aluno]
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List] for value '[Concluido]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.academy.model.Aluno]

Classe:

```
@Entity
```

public class Aluno{

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String nome;
private String curso;
private String idade;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dataCadastro;
@Column(name = "Turno")
private String horario;
private String status;
private String tel;
@Column(name = "telefone_alternativo")
private String telAlt;
```

//  Getters e Setters

```
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCurso() {
    return curso;
}
public void setCurso(String curso) {
    this.curso = curso;
}

public String getIdade() {
    return idade;
}
public void setIdade(String idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}
public Date getDataCadastro() {
    return dataCadastro;
}
public void setDataCadastro(Date dataCadastro) {
    this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
}
public String getHorario() {
    return horario;
}
public void setHorario(String horario) {
    this.horario = horario;
}
public String getTel() {
    return tel;
}
public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}
public String getTelAlt() {
    return telAlt;
}
public void setTelAlt(String telAlt) {
    this.telAlt = telAlt;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

não sei se é seu caso mas estava com memso erro, modifiquei minha query de:

```
@Query("SELECT clientes.cod_cliente, clientes.nome FROM Clientes clientes")
```

modifiquei para:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT clientes.cod_cliente, clientes.nome FROM Clientes clientes", nativeQuery = true)
```

e funcionou corretamente, essa segunda @Query eu afirmo que é uma query nativa Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta com problemas na serialização dos dados. Quem cuida disso é o Jackson através de reflection. Para resolver este caso, é preciso criar um DTO para serializar os dados que você realmente necessita. Você pode usar padrão de projeto converter ou Adapter para realizar a conversão dos dados e fazer a serialização manual.

Outra forma é criar um objeto de valor na qual o Jackon iria serializar para você. Por exemplo:

```
class AlunoStatusVO {
   String status
}
```

Esse valor, você retornaria na serialização do JPA através do Jackson.

Obs: Estou vendo alguma forma de o Jackson cuidar disso. Provavelmente irei alterar essa questão caso encontre alguma solução.